# How can I find out what type of entry is getting used?

Tags: templating, solspace, plugin-solspacecalendar

I have an include that is being used for plain entries, and is also being used for categories. (Categories have their own urls)

```
{% if entry is defined %}
    {% set entry = entry %}
{% elseif category is defined %}
    {% set entry = category %}
{% elseif event is defined %}
    {% set entry = event %}
{% endif %}

...

<h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>
```

I am using the [Solspace](https://solspace.com/craft/calendar/) Calendar and would like to use the same hero template. However, I'm getting the "entry is not defined". I am not sure what the calendar entry type is. Is there a way to output what Craft is expecting?

I have also tried:

```
{% if entry is defined %}
    {% set entry = entry %}
{% elseif category is defined %}
    {% set entry = category %}
{% elseif calendar is defined %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Not 100% sure on this so I'll wait till you confirm before I post this as an answer, but try `event` - http://docs.solspace.com/craft/calendar/v2/template-objects/event.html#properties